# Can't get loop to stop running

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that rolls 2 dice, calculates number of rolls for each side of the dice, calculates the actual and expected percents then asks the user to roll again. However, my loop wont ask the user if they want to continue or stop looping after 5 rolls.  I am not allowed to use arrays yet. I am a beginner. Thanks for the help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

   int i;
   int number;
   float expected_percent;
   int val2=1, val3=1,val4=1,val5=1,val6=1,val7=1;
   int val8=1,val9=1,val10=1,val11=1, val12=1 ;
   int val;


   int rollDice;
   int roll_1, roll_2;

   float perc2, perc3, perc4, perc5, perc6, perc7, perc8;
   float perc9, perc10, perc11, perc12;


   float exp2, exp3, exp4, exp5, exp6, exp7, exp8, exp9;
   float exp10, exp11, exp12;

   char ans, y, Y, n, N;

   srand(time(NULL));

   do{
    printf("How many times do you want to roll a dice ? \n \n ");
    scanf("%d/n/n",&number);

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        roll_1 = rand() %6+1;
        roll_2 = rand() %6 + 1;
        rollDice = roll_1 + roll_2;
        val = rollDice;
        switch (val){
            case 2:
                val2++;
                break;
            case 3:
                val3++;
                break;
            case 4:
                val4++;
                break;
            case 5:
                val5++;
                break;
            case 6:
                val6++;
                break;
            case 7:
                val7++;
                break;
            case 8:
                val8++;
                break;
            case 9:
                val9++;
                break;
            case 10:
                val10++;
                break;
            case 11:
                val11++;
                break;
            case 12:
                val12++;
                break;
        }
    }

    perc2 = (float)(100 *(float)val2/number);
    perc3 = (float)(100 *(float)val3/number);
    perc4 = (float)(100 *(float)val4/number);
    perc5 = (float)(100 *(float)val5/number);
    perc6 = (float)(100 *(float)val6/number);
    perc7 = (float)(100 *(float)val7/number);
    perc8 = (float)(100 *(float)val8/number);
    perc9 = (float)(100 *(float)val9/number);
    perc10 = (float)(100 *(float)val10/number);
    perc11 = (float)(100 *(float)val11/number);
    perc12 = (float)(100 *(float)val12/number);

    exp2 = (perc2 / number) * 36;
    exp3 = (perc3 / number) * 36;
    exp4 = (perc4 / number) * 36;
    exp5 = (perc5 / number) * 36;
    exp6 = (perc6 / number) * 36;
    exp7 = (perc7 / number) * 36;
    exp8 = (perc8 / number) * 36;
    exp9 = (perc9 / number) * 36;
    exp10 = (perc10 / number) * 36;
    exp11 = (perc11 / number) * 36;
    exp12 = (perc12 / number) * 36;

    printf("\n\nRoll\tTotal\tSession\t Expected\n\n");

    printf("2\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val2, perc2, exp2);
    printf("3\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val3, perc3, exp3);
    printf("4\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val4, perc4, exp4);
    printf("5\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val5, perc5, exp5);
    printf("6\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val6, perc6, exp6);
    printf("7\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val7, perc7, exp7);
    printf("8\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val8, perc8, exp8);
    printf("9\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val9, perc9, exp9);
    printf("10\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val10, perc10, exp10);
    printf("11\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val11, perc11, exp11);
    printf("12\t%d \t%.2f%% \t  %.2f%% \t \n",val12, perc12, exp12);
   }
   while (ans == Y || y);

   printf("\n\nWould you like to roll again? Please answer Y or N\n\n");
   scanf("%c", &ans);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code has bugs, FYI.  Try running it and entering in a letter.  ( This is because you're not checking the success of `sscanf`, which nobody on SE seems to do :) ).  I'm also pretty sure your results are wrong as I'm getting tens of thousands of percents but maybe _I_'m wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
    /* ... */
} while (ans == Y || y);
```

You should change this into

```
do {
    /* ... */
} while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code row:

```
char ans, y, Y, n, N;
```

must be this way:

```
char ans;
```

you don't need create the another chars, because the variable ans will assume the values 'y', 'Y', 'n' and 'N'. Then, if `(ans == 'y' || 'Y' )` is boolean true, will be because the user  typed 'y' or 'Y'.

And, like the partner Timrau says:

this code:

```
do{
    /* ... */
}while (ans == Y || y);
```

Must be:

```
do{
    /* ... */
}while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
```